# Memory snappiness docker

Tags: docker, debian

I have installed Docker 1.8.1 on Debian 8.1.

When I run docker info, I get:

```
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

There is a trick to enable memory swappiness:
https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#adjust-memory-and-swap-accounting

It is written on the above documentation that enabling memory swappiness does degrade performance.

Why should I enable this option if it degrades the performance of my system?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand without enabling memory and swap accounting we cannot limit Docker container memory usage, see -m options.

All has a price.

The follow up question: [Docker best practices about enabling memory and swap accounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582173/docker-best-practices-about-enabling-memory-and-swap-accounting)