# Docker best practices about enabling memory and swap accounting

Tags: docker

From Docker docs:

> Enabling memory and swap accounting does induce both a memory overhead
>   and a performance degradation even when Docker is not in use. The
>   memory overhead is about 1% of the total available memory. The
>   performance degradation is roughly 10%.

What is the best practices here?

- always enable this kernel feature
- enable only on hosts with multiple containers running
- may be something smart else

Comment: I would say enable when required. I run several containers a day, I never enable this feature as I have enough resources. So... Enable it when you need.

Note that you can also decide to share only specific CPU.